# Why does my factorial function output multiple incorrect lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, factorial

I have written a factorial function.

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n < 0:
        return "\n Factorial does not exist for negative numbers"
    elif n in (0,1):
        return "\n Factorial of the given value is 1"
    else:
        return (n * factorial(n-1))

num=int(input("Enter any integer value:"))
print(factorial(num))
```

The `if` and `elif` blocks are working fine; they correctly detect integers less than 2. But it seems like the `else` part is never run. When I enter num=3:

```
Enter any integer value:3

 Factorial of the given value is 1
 Factorial of the given value is 1
 Factorial of the given value is 1
 Factorial of the given value is 1
 Factorial of the given value is 1
 Factorial of the given value is 1
```

Instead of outputting "Factorial of the given value is 6", it repeatedly says "Factorial of the given value is 1". Can anyone point out what the issue here is, please?

Comment: Post code, not images of code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code as text, [not as a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Why does this `factorial` function return _strings_? Note that if `n` is an integer and `factorial(1)` returns a string, `n * factorial(n-1)` will return the string repeated at least `n` times.

Comment: so, I have to pass (factorial int n ). Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

The logic is wrong because you return the negative factorial message when n becomes 1.

Your code flow is this:

```
f(3) = 3 * f(2) = 3 * 2 * f(1) = 6 * f(1) = 6 * ( " Factorial of given value is 1 " )
```

That shows your approach is wrong. You can try this instead

```
def factorial(n):
   if n == 1 or n < 0:
       return n
   else:
       return n*factorial(n-1)
```

Comment: Technically, it's doing `3 * (2 * "the string")`, not `(3 * 2) * "the string"` – but I get why that was too verbose to write in your answer. Good explanation.

Comment: Your code gives the wrong answer for factorial(0). 0 factorial is 1 but your code gives it 0. Also the factorial of negative numbers doesn't exist but your code just returns the input in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't multiply a string by a number, that is the problem. Try:

```
def factorial(x):
    if x == 0:
        return(1)
    else:
        return(x*factorial(x-1))
```

Of course you'll need to add the error handling (your code implies it may encounter negative numbers but also consider what should happen if x is not an integer) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Computers don't speak English.

When representing data internally, you need to represent it in a machine-readable form. Your function's representation of 1! is the string `"\n Factorial of the given value is 1"`. What does it even *mean* to multiply this by `2`?

Well, actually, Python *does* have a meaning assigned to `int * str`:

```
>>> 3 * "hi "
'hi hi hi '
```

By this accident of Python's design, your program outputs 6 lines for `print(factorial(3))`, 120 lines for `print(factorial(5))`, and so on. `return 1` instead, and you'll see the answer you expect.

---

While you're at it, you should represent the error condition `n < 0` in machine-readable form, too. `raise ValueError` is a good way of doing that. Here's a version with exceptions, and some miscellaneous [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) improvements thrown in:

```py
def factorial(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError("Factorial does not exist for negative numbers")
    if n in (0, 1):
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = int(input("Enter any integer value: "))
    print("Factorial of the given value is", factorial(num))
```

If we run this:

```
Enter any integer value: 3
6
>>> factorial(5)
120
>>> factorial(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    factorial(-1)
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 3, in factorial
    raise ValueError("Factorial does not exist for negative numbers")
ValueError: Factorial does not exist for negative numbers
>>> try:
...     print(factorial(1.5))
... except ValueError as e:
...     print(e)
...
Factorial does not exist for negative numbers
```

Comment: Nice answer! But I think that maybe teach to use `raise` is premature for someone who asked a simple question like this

Comment: They wanted to return an error condition. In some languages (like Rust and C) you _do_ `return` error conditions, but in Python you `raise` them. It's probably premature, but they can just ignore the second part of the answer if they're not ready for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the result diretcly from de function return, this is unecessary.

You can set the result for a variable and use this to concatenate like this

```py
num=int(input("Enter any integer value:"))
result = factorial(num)
print ("Factorial of", num, "is", result)
```

Also you need to change you function to process with integer only,the way you are doing it now performs string multiplication operations, which is not what we want.

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    elif n in (0,1):
        return 1
    else:
        return (n * factorial(n-1))
```

Answer (score -4):

simplest factorial python program is;

num = int(input())

any = 0

while i<=num:

any = any*i
i+=1

print("Factorail:" , any)

Comment: [Try to provide an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/9898033) that will lead the asker in the correct direction.

Comment: You should format code correctly with indents.

Comment: iam new to stackoverflow, dont know how to to add TAB, will search about its usage